# Crystal Reports Selection Formula Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Recently I have been trying to add a selection formula from the code (C#). The report's data is coming from the view "**view_rpt_inquiry**". What I needed to do is to filter all the records by start date and end date to get all the inquiries in between. So my selection formula is, (Without the selection formula it works fine), But with it, it gives me an error **"Failed to retrieve the data from the database"**

```
myCrystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = "{view_rpt_inquiry.Date} >= '01/07/2014' and {view_rpt_inquiry.Date} <= '30/07/2014' ";
```

Please can someone show me what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by setting the following as my selection formula

```
myCrystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = "Date({view_rpt_inquiry.Date}) in Date('01/07/2014') to Date('30/07/2014')";
```